# "docker-machine" stuck at "Creating SSH key"

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, docker

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12 and I'm trying to create new docker-machine and I get stuck at following:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/alexus/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/alexus/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
```

Any ideas? I'm using latest Docker Toolbox and latest VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too. It ended up being permissions on the default machine that was created using the docker toolbox script. I had to delete the directory `~/.docker/machine/machines/default` and then run docker-machine create default -d virtualbox manually.

Comment: Worked for me too with a fresh install of docker on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar on 10.11.6, and enabled debugging (`docker-machine -D create ...`). The process seemed to stall at "Filling zeroes" (ie. writing  zeroes to the vmdk), which seemed odd given that I had decreased the disk size to 20GB and was using on an SSD.

That lead me to this [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730829/docker-machine-create-breaks-at-dbg-filling-zeroes?rq=1), whose accepted answer states:

> Docker isn't actually broken, it just takes EXTREMELY long to provision Virtual Box the first time. For my Late 2013 MacBook Pro with SSD it took ~1 hour to complete the first time.
> After the initial provisioning of the default machine everything works
> like normal.